# Insert hyphen(-) automatically while typing an SSN in a Textbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi I am building an application where user have to enter SSN into a textbox. Is it possible to insert hyphen(-) automatically like while typing 123 hyphen after 3 i.e 123-. In the same way after typing 123-45 hyphen after 5 i.e 123-45-. Finally 123-45-6789   . I must be able to change number if entered wrongly.

Comment: even i'm interested to see how one would implement this.. :) thanks for posting this up! will wait for answers from the community..

Comment: It is possible that this is a hard requirement for your project, but I would ask you to consider whether this will make it easier or harder for the user to type in the SSN. In my personal experience typing thing into sites that suddenly change what I typed in and make it difficult to edit thing makes for a frustrating experience.

Answer (score 9):

I think this one can help

[Masked input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo)

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to have the textbox already populated by

```
 __-__-____
```

and as the user types in a number or a backspace, change the data.

Answer (score 0):

It will be pretty hard for the user if the system puts some characters when he is typing. Allow the user to enter his number and then when he changes focus from the textbox you can show the altered string in a preview pane.